# How to add site to package

Tags: package, site.com

I want to add a site to the package. How can i add a site to a package. I am not able to find the site for adding to the package in add section.

Answer (score 4):

Site.com isn't currently supported for managed packages - the list of supported components is available at:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_packageable_components.htm

According to the Spring 14 release notes (safe harbor), site.com will be supported by the metadata api so packaging may be supported in the future:

- [Spring ’14 Release Notes: Deploying Sites with the Metadata API](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_sitecom_mdata_site_create.htm)

(Note that the release notes mention creating a package, but this appears to be another term for deployment as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 3):

Per Bob's answer, Sites are not currently packageable. (Or deleteable).

However if you are distributing some package that inherently integrates with a Force.com Site, you can reduce a great deal of the manual post-install steps by packaging a Permission Set containing:

- Apex Class access
- Visualforce Page access
- Object CRUD permissions
- Field Level Security permissions

Then in your documentation, instruct users to create (or edit) their Site, go to Public Access Settings > View Users, then create a `Permission Set Assignment` on the `Site Guest User`

Answer (score 1):

> The Salesforce site object isn’t packageable. Make sure that the
> destination org has a site with the same developer name as the site in
> the source org where the package is created.

- [ISVforce Guide: Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm)

> Sites are not packageable. However, you can package sample code,
> Visualforce pages, Apex classes, or components for a site using a
> managed package.

- [Salesforce Sites Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_considerations.htm&type=5)